# csv to latex chart

Tags: tabularx, csvsimple

What I want: to make a chart from a csv file (exp1.csv).

Problem:

1. I don't get all the data visible in the chart
2. The header of my table is not consistent (see \hline)
   Could you help me to solve those two problems?

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{float}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{exp1.csv}
Ultrapure,0.406,0.384,0.362
Deionized,2.78,2.769,2.603
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Characterisation of chemicals}
\begin{table}[ht]{
\scalebox{1}{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y||Y|Y|}
\bfseries Water type & \bfseries value 1 & \bfseries value 2\\
\csvreader[head to column names]{exp1.csv}{}
{\\\hline\csvcoli&\csvcolii& \csvcoliii}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your `csv` file has four columns, hence I guess your tabular also need four columns.
- Your `csv` contains no table head, hence the use of option `no head`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{float}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{exp1.csv}
Ultrapure,0.406,0.384,0.362
Deionized,2.78,2.769,2.603
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Characterisation of chemicals}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*3{|Y}|Y|}
    \hline
    \bfseries Water type & \bfseries value 1 & \bfseries value 2 & \bfseries value 3
    \csvreader[no head]{exp1.csv}{}{\\ \hline \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv}
    \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Follow-up: Multi-page tables with `X` column type

- Load `ltablex` and uses `\keepXColumns` to activate the effect of `X` column type.
- Move `tabularx` environment output of `table` floating environment, and use `tabularx` like `longtable` environment. For example, use `\caption{...} \\` in `tabularx` to put an caption.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
  \keepXColumns

\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{float}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{exp1.csv}
Ultrapure,0.406,0.384,0.362
Deionized,2.78,2.769,2.603
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Characterisation of chemicals}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}
    \caption{text} \\
    \hline
    \bfseries Water type & \bfseries value 1 & \bfseries value 2 & \bfseries value 3
    \csvreader[no head]{exp1.csv}{}{\\ \hline \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv}
    \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you! amazing :D

Comment: Do you know how to make this table span multiple pages because with longpages instead tabularx it changes the whole layout

Comment: @Elia: `xltabular` combines the features of `tabularx` (`X` type columns)  and `longtable`(mid-table page breaks). Why would you need `tabularx` in the first place for this specific table? The only thing it does here is artificially making the table a lot wider than it needs to be, making it less readable.

Comment: @Elia I've appended a multi-page table with `X` column type to my answer.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ thank you! your answer is very helpful

Comment: one last question. do you know how I can get the data not in bold format in the multi-page table (code above)?

Comment: @Elia Delete `\bfseries` used in first row of `xtabular`.